# нужно найти нужные комбинации в выборке

Tags: r

Вопрос к тем кто очень хорошо разбирается в R.

Есть у меня выборка с самом стандартом ее виде, 10 колонок наблюдений(V1,V2...V10) и целевая фун. (Label)

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 Label
1   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     1
2   2  4  9  5  8  2  7  6  3   4     0
3   4  6  8  4  4 10  6 10  5   2     1
4   6  2  2  9  7  4  3  9  7   7     0
5   7  1  7  6 10  8  5  3  1   3     1
6   8  5  5  8  1  7  4  1  2  10     0
7   9  8  1 10  5  6  2  5 10   8     0
8   5  7 10  3  3  5  8  4  9   6     1
9  10  9  6  2  6  9  9  2  4   1     0
10  1 10  4  7  2  1  1  8  8   9     1
```

(Эта выборка чисто для наглядного примера на самом деле колонок будет намного больше, а строк около 100-900 тыс)

Мне нужно ...

1) перебрать всю выборку и найти такие строки которые повторяются не менее "n"- раз, ну скажем 10 раз и больше

типа :

```
  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10
1   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5
2   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5
3   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5
4   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5
5   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5
6   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5
7   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5
8   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5
9   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5
10  3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5
```

2)  Нужно чтобы в этих найденных строках единичек в целевой(Label) было бы минимум в 5-раз больше чем нулей

типа :

```
V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 V7 V8 V9 V10 Label
1   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     1
2   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     1
3   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     1
4   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     1
5   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     0
6   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     1
7   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     1
8   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     0
9   3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     1
10  3  3  3  1  9  3 10  7  6   5     1
```

Те мы ищем такие идентичные строки в которых "концентрация" единичек в Label очень высока

3) Мы ищем комбинации не только просто по строкам а еще и перебираем все комбинации из колонок те пробуем различные комбинации из колонок(V1...V10) в поисках этой "концентрации" единичек в Label

4) Как это выглядит "пример": путем перебора мы находим комбинацию из напр. V1,V5,V8,V9

V1=3, V5=1, V8=5, V9=5  - и эта комбинация попадалась не менее 10 раз и в этой комбинации "концентрация" единичек в Label очень высока, минимум в 5 раз больше чем нулей

5)Когда мы найдем такую комбинацию из примера 4) тогда записываемым эту комбинацию  в какой то лист где записываем эту строку , сколько раз она попадалась и какое соотношение было единичек к нулям в Label

Сам процесс получиться очень затратный по времени, так что нужно использовать самые быстрые алгоритмы и пакеты для этого..

Comment: Честно говоря совсем не понятно , что делаете и что хотите получить. 1) данные -- используете `dput` 2)если уже есть код который работает медленно, покажите его  3) думаю стоит конкретизировать проблему

Comment: Приведите полноценный пример данных и ожидаемый результат.

Comment: Артем, эта проблема уже давно решена, все работает, все устраивает... Сейчас у меня одна беда с dtw http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/608436/%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-dtw-%D0%B2-r-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-rccp

Answer (score 1):

По первому вопросу:

```
v1 <- 1:10
v2 <- 2:11
v3 <- 3:12
df <- data.frame(v1 = v1, v2 = v2, v3 = v3)
df$ind = do.call(paste0,  df)
as.data.frame(table(df$ind))
```

Дальше остается только отсортировать полученную таблицу и работать с теми строками, для которых частота выше нужного порога.

По второму вопросу: `tapply` и `mean` помогут вычислить искомую "долю единичек" (в векторе 1, 1, 0, 0, доля единичек - это среднее значение), дальше снова фильтрация нужных наблюдений по условию.

Остальное не понял, и вообще - вопросы задаются по одному, а не по 5 в одном сообщении.

P.s. для скорости все можно делать с использованием пакета data.table