# нужно перенести алгоритм dtw в R с помощью Rccp

Tags: c++, r

В R есть пакет с dtw алгоритмом но он очень медленный, я решил его заменить на dtw который написан на с++ 
от [сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36675738/dtw-algorithm-oct-file)
.
Скажу сразу, я только изучаю програмирование и R мой первый язык, с другими языками я не знаком и с с++ в частности тоже, так что не удивляйтесь если я чего то не понимаю, даже если ето что то очень тривиальное...

Все что мне нужно от функции это чтоб она принимала на вход два вектора произвольной длинны и на выходе давала евклидову дистанцию между этими векторами те меру близости, и все.. максимально быстро и максимально коротко

Итак взял я код из выше указанной ссылки и попробовал его интегрировать в R с помощью Rccp 
Но не заработало, мне кажется что в начале как то не правильно объявляться переменные и их типы

```
#include <Rcpp.h>

using namespace Rcpp;




DEFUN_DLD (dtw3, args, , "Find DTW of two signals with window")
{

  int nargin = args.length();

  if (nargin != 2)
    print_usage();

  Matrix A = args(0).array_value();
  Matrix B = args(1).array_value();

  octave_stdout << "Size of A is " << A.length() << std::endl;;
  octave_stdout << "Size of B is " << B.length() << std::endl;

  if (! error_state)
    {
      octave_idx_type n = A.length();
      octave_idx_type m = B.length();

      Matrix results (n + 1, m + 1);

      for(octave_idx_type i = 0; i <= n ; i++)
        for(octave_idx_type j = 0; j <= m ; j++)
          results(i, j) = octave_Inf;
      results(0, 0) = 0;

      octave_idx_type win = abs (n-m);

      double cost = 0;

      for(octave_idx_type i = 1 ; i <= n ; i++)
        for(octave_idx_type j = std::max(1, i-win) ; j <= std::min(m, i+win) ; j++)
          {
            cost = abs(A(i-1) - B(j-1));
            results(i, j) = cost + std::min(std::min(results(i-1,j),results(i,j-1)),results(i-1,j-1));
          }

      //octave_stdout << results << std::endl;
      return ovl(results(n, m));
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста что нужно изменить в этом коде?

Comment: Ошибки при компиляции, или уже в процессе работы?

Comment: при компиляции. Хочу заметить что можно использовать любой код, не обязательно этот, мне главное получить dtw функцию с выше описными свойствами и чтобы она работала быстро

Comment: Ошибку в студию! И укажите среду в которой работаете версию компилятора и ОС.

Comment: R version 3.3.1         ////        среда :    R-Studio Version 0.99.902      /////     Windows 7    ///  версию компилятора для с++ не знаю где там смотреть

Comment: Ошибки :        http://prntscr.com/dofmh4  эта с консоли Р-студии :   Error in Rcpp::sourceCpp("C:/Users/TARAS/Desktop/dtw.cpp") :  
  Error 1 occurred building shared library.                                                                          эта я так понял от компилятора с++ http://prntscr.com/dofm6t

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21306916/1863950

Comment: Нет Артем, там не то, там делают саму функцию fast.dist() в c++ и внедряют ее в штатный алгоритм dtw из library(dtw) тем самым ускоряют его где то в три раза, а я хотел бы весь dtw внедрить из с++ , это даст прирост думаю в 500 раз, и еще там есть отличие, они ищут близость в матрицах а я в векторах

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит? `euc.dist <- function(x1, x2) sqrt(sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2))`

Comment: Если я правильно понял, то вы предлагаете просто мерить  "euc.dist" вместо "dtw.dist"? Так я сначала и предполагал , но потом попробовал dtw и оказалось что для моей задачи он (dtw) не то что лучше работает чем "euc.dist" , а скорей "euc.dist" вообще не работает по сравнению с "dtw.dist"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Эквивалентный код с `Rcpp`:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
double dtw_rcpp(const NumericVector& x, const NumericVector& y) {
    size_t n = x.size(), m = y.size();
    NumericMatrix res = no_init(n + 1, m + 1);
    std::fill(res.begin(), res.end(), R_PosInf);
    res(0, 0) = 0;
    double cost = 0;
    size_t w = std::abs(static_cast<int>(n - m));
    for (size_t i = 1; i <= n; ++i) {
        for (size_t j = std::max(1, static_cast<int>(i - w)); j <= std::min(m, i + w); ++j) {
            cost = std::abs(x[i - 1] - y[j - 1]);
            res(i, j) = cost + std::min(std::min(res(i - 1, j), res(i, j - 1)), res(i - 1, j - 1));
        }
    }
    return res(n, m);
}
```

Сам алгоритм также описан в [Википедии](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping#Implementation).

Comment: Спасибо Артем и С новым Годом вас!!!  Я  результат работы вашего кода с штатным dtw ... Есть две новости одна хорошая другая плохая , хорошая в том что ваш алгоритм работает в 140 раз быстрее, а плохая в том что результаты алгоритмы выдают разные , вот результат обработки одинаковых данных > dtw.orig$distance  
==18.22887
________________
 dtw_1(x,y)
==11.4879

Comment: Поправил код. Правда, я не уверен, что `dtw::dtw` использует тот же алгоритм, поэтому результаты могут различаться.

Comment: В функции dtw из пакета dtw есть три вида нахождения пути в матрице расстояний это  symmetric2, symmetric1,asymmetric. В выше представленом коде с++ реализуется вариант symmetric1, потому и было не сходство с пакетом dtw потому что у него  по умолчанию стоит symmetric2. По моим исследования  symmetric2 очень сильно отличается в лучшую сторону по сравнению с symmetric1, подскажите пожалуйста как посмотреть реализацию именно этого метода, ну или может код есть? спасибо

Comment: Изучите исходный код пакета и справку.

Comment: в справке написано просто общими фразами те не понятно без формул, а в исходнике не могу разобраться, там как то кучеряво очень, по факту кода по symmetric2 я там вообще не нашел

Comment: http://prntscr.com/ds5b4e вот как это понять?  https://github.com/cran/dtw/blob/master/R/stepPattern.R